# Covert left join to simple join

Tags: sql, join, subquery

My LEFT JOIN subquery is taking longer. How do I covert it to JOIN?

```
SELECT  * FROM "TABLE_A" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.mainid = TABLE_B.secondID       
LEFT JOIN (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
           SELECT secondID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
           FROM  TABLE_C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
           WHERE thirdID = 21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          ) Z ON TABLE_A.mainid = Z.secondID 
WHERE "TABLE_A"."TRUEID" = 9 
   AND ((TABLE_A.USERNO IN (23))
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You know that LEFT OUTER JOIN and LEFT JOIN are the same? Stick to one of them to make code clearer to understand.

Comment: There's a reason for LEFT JOIN and there's a reason for INNER JOIN. Both have unique uses. If your query takes longer to process it's not because of a LEFT or INNER JOIN, you might work on indexing. Check your Actual Execution Plan and see where the query spends most resources.

Comment: "takes longer" than what? Why does that matter? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write the query more concisely:

```
SELECT *
FROM "TABLE_A" a LEFT JOIN
     TABLE_B b
     ON a.mainid = b.secondID LEFT JOIN    
     TABLE_C c
      ON a.mainid = c.secondID AND c.thirdID = 21 
WHERE a."TRUEID" = 9 AND a.USERNO IN (23);
```

Then consider the indexes:

- `Table_A(TRUEID, USERNO, mainid)`
- `Table_B(secondID)`
- `Table_C(secondID, thirdID)`

Comment: Thank You Gordon. Appreciate the quick response.